# Sending keystrokes to a single program

Tags: .net, process, bots, keystrokes

Is there a way to send keystrokes to 1 single process/program?

By doing so you should be able to send keystrokes only to this single process/program(while it is minimized) so the keystrokes aren't recognized by the other programs.

ps. this would be used for bots in certain games

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is OS-specific; on Unix systems, you'd use the XTEST extension, and on Windows, you'd post to the program's event queue. The [`Robot` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) might be of some use to you, though it has limitations. Anything more involved will require using the OS's native API.

Answer (score 1):

In `java` it's not possible to get `keystrokes` if the program scree is not `visible`.

You can do this in `.net` (c# or VB).